# mongoose peek at first document in array

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to peek at the first element in an array being saved in mongoose. Let's say it looks like this:

`var batterySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    percent: Number, 
    minutes: Number,
    time: Date,
})
var robotSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    battery_life: [batterySchema],
});`

And I am going to be constantly adding elements to the battery_life document for a particular robot using unshift.

Now if at any time I want to be able to grab the latest battery_life element, it seems that I can pop off of that array and just not save. But I can't figure out if that is bad in some way. I would be more comfortable with a dedicated peek function, but can't find one.

Alternatively, I could just add another field that always has the latest battery status. Would that be better?

Answer (score 0):

You could use projection to project only the first array element.

Assuming your Mongoose model is **Robot**, this should work:

```
Robot.find({}, { "battery_life.0": 1 }, function(err, docs) {
  // Callback code
})
```

This will just return the **_id** field (returned by default) and the first item from the **battery_life** array for the matched documents.

If you need just the last item in the array then this should work instead:

```
Robot.find({}, { "battery_life": { $slice: -1 } }, function(err, docs) {
  // Callback code
})
```